# How did the strangers sync the memories of all the inhabitants?

Tags: dark-city

In *Dark City* (1998), the strangers didn't imprint everyone when they were 'tuning'. Besides, some of the buildings were also considerably altered during the process. How did they sync the memories of all the inhabitants?

Comment: With psychic powers

Comment: @Valorum They didn't show such power on screen except making people sleep (short-distance ability).

Comment: Well, no, they show it over and over again when they make alterations and nobody notices. You're right that it's implied rather than stated. I mean it's equally possible that extreme inattentiveness is simply programmed into them when they're imprinted

Comment: As I understood it, the imprinting is used only to give someone a new set of "old" memories -- effectively, change who they are (how they grew up, etc.), vs. unneeded for things like "how to get to work, where's the barber shop and theater" type knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Been a while since I've seen the movie (got a DVD copy, though).  As I recall, based on the scenes where Schreber is guiding Murdoch through the memories he was supposed to receive before he woke up during a Tuning, the imprint is about establishing who a person remembers being -- how and where they grew up, who are relatives and old friends, the (long past) events that shape their personality (like the trips to Shell Beach or the fire for Murdoch).

Other, more trivial things are apparently part of the tuning -- if buildings are added, deleted, moved, resized, etc., everyone automatically remembers the "new" street layout, how to get to work, the barber shop, the bar or restaurant, etc.

Only Murdoch avoids this, because he didn't sleep during the Tuning (after waking up the first time) -- and this, we might presume, is because Schreber has managed to imprint him with the ability to Tune for himself.